# How to force GCC to put constants in memory instead of generating them?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, constants

I have a *lot* of constant arrays defined in several functions. Something like the following:

```
const float values[4] = {-4312.435f,  -432.44333f,  4.798, 7898.89};
```

After inspecting gcc assembler output I noticed that these constants are generated on each run of the functions. That's quite inefficient. I suspect that this is because C/C++ spec says that even if data is `const`, the compiler can't assume it won't be modified (e.g. through const_cast). Is it possible to force gcc think otherwise?

I want to keep these constants defined inside the bodies of the functions, because they are quite complex. Keeping constants near where they're used helps with the maintainability a lot.

**EDIT**

Unfortunatelly, even when the constants are defined `static`, they are regenerated on the each run. I use -O3 if that helps.

**EDIT2**

Ok, sorry regarding the first edit, I need to investigate further. It seems that particular setup previously somehow didn't allow gcc to initialize the constants without regenerating them.

**EDIT3**

The problem was in my testcase, where I defined two arrays nearby, but one of them was intended to be generated. The assembler then misled me. Sorry again & thanks!

Comment: What if you make the constants static? I think this will then place them on the stack.

Comment: No, `static` specifier places constants outside stack. But surprisingly, gcc still regenerates them on each run of the function.

Comment: @jons34yp, can you post your code? How do you check, does gcc regenerate a constant or not?

Comment: @jwir3: right idea, wrong reasoning. They already are being put on the stack - that is the default for all local variables. Using `static` causes the compiler to create the array only once, rather than recreating it each time it is used.

Comment: @jons34yp: if it does, then I suppose that must be because it thinks doing so unconditionally is faster than checking whether the array is already initialized. So if you still have a provable performance problem I guess the next step is to move the array outside the function.

Comment: @Mac: Why is this? Is it unique to gcc?

Comment: @jwir3: as a reasonable approximation, compilers will store function statics in the same place as globals. Obviously it's up to the implementation, but they're basically the same thing with different visibility.

Comment: @jwir3: no, that's the definition of `static` (at least, in this particular context).

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this behavior with a simple test function.  Could you show a complete example function that produces bad code?

Comment: Are all your arrays this small ? Testing shows larger arrays are not loaded each time. I'd profile this though, g++ might be doing the right thing - the penalty of addressing stuff far away might be greater than loading them each time, and you might benefit from the instruction cache (vs addressing data thats potentially not in any cache) You can always test this by placing the arrays in a separate compilation unit and declaring them extern in the code that uses the arrays

Comment: Compiler does a reasonable optimization using the literals in place. This is much faster than accessing memory.

Comment: 1) `static_cast` cannot cast away constness; 2) `const_cast` would invoke an undefined behavior. Compiler is absolutely correct optimizing away consts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Declare them with the `static` keyword.

Edit:  responding to your comment so I can show you some code:

This is the expected behavior.  Are you doing or seeing something different?

```
$ cat foo.c++
int main(void)
{
    static const float foos[] = {1.234f, 5.678f, 9.012f};
    return 0;
}
$ g++ -S foo.c++
$ cat foo.s
    .file   "foo.c++"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .rodata
    .align 4
    .type   _ZZ4mainE4foos, @object
    .size   _ZZ4mainE4foos, 12
_ZZ4mainE4foos:
    .long   1067316150
    .long   1085649453
    .long   1091580199
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly gcc still regenerates the constants

Comment: @jons34yp: What do you mean by regenerates the constants?  I tried a small example myself, and a function containing `const float values[4] = {1,2,3,4};` was compiled as a lot of `mov` instructions, but the corresponding function using `static` did not contain those `mov` instructions.

Comment: try to use a some of values in the function.

Comment: @jons34yp, see edit above.  With `static` there are no instructions which "regenerate" any constants here.

Comment: @osgx, what are you getting at?  If you actually use them then the compiler will generate instructions to move the values from the memory location at `_ZZ4mainE4foos` to (floating point) registers.

Answer (score 11):

The compiler actually can assume that values defined as `const` will never change.  (Things accessed via a `const` variable are another story; I'm only talking about cases when the definition is visible and has `const`.)  The gotcha that is getting ya here is that the Standard says if you call your function recursively, the address of `values` will be different each time.

So use the language feature that means the declaration refers to the same thing each time the function is called.  That is, a `static` function variable:

```
static const float values[4] = {-4312.435f, -432.44333f, 4.798, 7898.89};
```

Comment: This is a good answer. +1 for explaining rather than just giving the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Change the definition to

```
static const float values[4] = {-4312.435f,  -432.44333f,  4.798, 7898.89};
```

Static arrays will not be placed in stack of function, so they will be not regenerated for each function call.

You can also try to move this array outside from function (make it a global array with some prefix like `function1_values`).

EDIT:

If you counts the `"flds"` or `"movss"` instuctions as regenerating - the are not. The constants will be stored in `.rodata` section of the elf file, but to use them, compiler must load them into registers. So `fld` & `movss` will only load the constant from memory and it is impossible to get value from memory without loading it.

The sample code:

```
int function4(float *a, int sz)
{
    int i;
const float values[4] = {-4312.435f,  -432.44333f,  4.798, 7898.89};
    for(i=4;i<sz;i++);
        a[i]+=a[i-1]*values[0]+a[i-2]*values[1]+a[i-3]*values[2]+a[i-4]*values[3];
    return i;
}
```

gcc-4.5.2 -O3 a.c -fverbose-asm -mfpmath=sse -march=native -S

Assembelr for loop body:

```
.L2:
    movl    -20(%ebp), %ecx # %sfp, D.2677
    leal    (%edx,%ecx), %ecx       #, D.2677  
    movss   .LC0, %xmm0     #, tmp192     << THIS is a constant loading
    mulss   (%edx,%edi), %xmm0      #* prephitmp.46, tmp192
    movss   .LC1, %xmm1     #, tmp179
    mulss   (%edx,%esi), %xmm1      #* prephitmp.46, tmp179
    addss   %xmm1, %xmm0    # tmp179, tmp192
    movss   .LC2, %xmm1     #, tmp183
    mulss   (%edx,%ebx), %xmm1      #* prephitmp.46, tmp183
    addss   %xmm1, %xmm0    # tmp183, tmp192
    movss   .LC3, %xmm1     #, tmp187
    movl    -16(%ebp), %ebx # %sfp,
```

And constants are stored at `.rodata`:

```
    .section        .rodata.cst4,"aM",@progbits,4
    .align 4
.LC0:
    .long   -981023877
    .align 4
.LC1:
    .long   -1009239873
    .align 4
.LC2:
    .long   1083803959
    .align 4
.LC3:
    .long   1173804831
```

Comment: `const` already means internal linkage, `static` is superfluous

Comment: Actually, in my example the const array and the static const array generate the same code (!)

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev, there can be 2 cases: global const array and local const array (declared in the function)

Answer (score 1):

Place all your

```
const float values[4] = {-4312.435f,  -432.44333f,  4.798, 7898.89};
```

in a separate .cpp file.

Declare them extern in the file that uses these arrays

```
extern const float values[4];
```

Though, as mentioned in the comments, profile this (in a real app where these arrays might be thrown out of the l1/l2 caches). This might, for non-intutive reasons, decrease performance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where you see the problem, compiler does a reasonable thing optimizing away the constants. You can prevent that by requiring external linkage:

```
extern const float values[4];
```